# Is there a psychological basis for getting hiccups?

Tags: physiology

Is getting the hiccups sometimes related to our mental condition, i.e., stress level, etc?

Comment: Had read it in an elementary science book (if you insist I'll dig for the name) that it is because of lack of carbon dioxide in the blood. And if you try to hold your breath for long it will be go away. Why does lack of carbon dioxide cause that, I don't know.

Comment: I tried to make this more in line with the site's scope.  Feel free to make any modifications as you see fit.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and better suited for biology.SE and lacks initial research like [consulting wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiccup#Causes).

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev it is on topic see my answer